# What is the point of Hataras Nedarim every year? 

Tags: halacha, minhag, nedarim-shevuot

The second paragraph of Hataras Nedarim has the person being mattired saying that "I am making a modaah that any oaths being made in the future are considered to be as if 'bli neder'".

Is this legally binding? If yes, why make a hataras nedarim every year?

Comment: I suggest you change "Is this legally binding? If yes, why make a hataras nedarim every year?" to "If this is legally binding, why make a hataras nedarim every year? And if not, why make it at all?" to focus the question on the every year aspect and not the binding aspect. (This is how I understood the question anyway.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29250/759

Answer (score 2):

As its wording implies, the *modaa* applies only to vows taken when one doesn't remember having issued the *modaa*. Source: *Shulchan Aruch*, *Yore Dea* 211:2, q.v.

Comment: Why repeat it yearly though?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the question didn't ask why repeat the ***modaa*** yearly. It asked, assuming each (year _n_) _modaa_ is valid, why make a ***hatara*** every year (_n_ + 1). And I think that's pretty clear in my answer without my spelling it out.

Comment: @msh210 I don't think it's so clear. If I were trying to maximise the effectiveness of my modaa, wouldn't I never say it again so that I really do forget about it?