# Can one rely on Kol Nidrei?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, nedarim-shevuot, kol-nidre

In [Kol Nidrei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kol_Nidre#Text), one says

> All vows, and prohibitions, and oaths, and consecrations, and konams and konasi and any synonymous terms, **that we may vow, or swear**, or consecrate, or prohibit upon ourselves, from the previous Day of Atonement until this Day of Atonement and ... **from this Day of Atonement until the Day of Atonement that will come** for our benefit. Regarding all of them, we repudiate them. **All of them are undone, abandoned, cancelled, null and void**, not in force, and not in effect. Our vows are no longer vows, and our prohibitions are no longer prohibitions, and **our oaths are no longer oaths**."

[Emphasis mine].

Does this mean that I am allowed to make a false (future, and not-interpersonal) oath nowadays?

---

The Wikipedia article says that many were opposed to this prayer for this reason. Yet, now that we do say it, why does one have to keep any not-interpersonal vow nowadays?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20295/759

Comment: Not everyone includes the line "from this one to the next one" so for them the prayer is only about the past. (Your question still applies to some groups; I'm just pointing out not all have this issue.)

Comment: @DoubleAA that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the Artscroll Yom Kippur Machzor:

> There is a dangerous and erroneous misconception among some people that the *Kol Nidre* nullification of vows - whether past or future, depending on the previously discussed opinions - gives people the right to break their word or to make insincere promises that will have no legal force. This is not the case. The *Kol Nidre* declaration can invalidate only vows that one undertakes on his own volition. It has *no* effect on vows or oaths imposed by someone else, a court, or a gentile.
>
> Also, the invalidation of future vows takes effect only if someone makes the vow without having in mind his previous *Kol Nidre* declaration. But if he makes the vow with *Kol Nidre* in mind - thus being openly insincere in his vow - the vow is in full force.

Comment: What about a voluntary vow to do or give something to another person (i.e. not imposed by another)?