# If Kol Nidre is effective, why do people do hatarat nedarim?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, kol-nidre

It seems to be unnecessary. Also, why do the specific Hatarat Nedarim on Erev Rosh Hashanah if we do it anyway just before Yom Kippur?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20295/16706

Comment: Why assume kol nidrei is effective?

Comment: If it's not effective, why do it?

Comment: No one knows because no one can figure out what is accomplishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**yeshiva.co** was posed this question ("[Hatarat Nedarim & Kol Nidrei](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4200)") and responded:

> 1) The most common answer [...] is that **Kol Nidrei** refers to the vows of the community, while **Hatarat Nedarim** takes care of personal vows.
>
> 2) On another level, **Kol Nidrei** (according to one Nusach) frees us from future vows only if the condition is forgotten later, while **Hatarat 
>   Nedarim** is for all personal vows.

While this answer doesn't cite sources, **dafyomi.co.il**'s "[insights to Nedarim 23](https://dafyomi.co.il/nedarim/insites/nd-dt-023.htm)" cite Rishonim who also distinguish between the two:

> The **Meiri** writes that "Kol Nidrei" does not serve to annul ordinary Nedarim. Rather, it serves to annul the Nedarim and Charamim made by the community, the Tzibur, as a whole. The removal of such Nedarim required neither the Hatarah of a Chacham or Beis Din nor Charatah, and thus it may be done through the recitation of "Kol Nidrei."

This sounds like reason #1 cited above.

> The **Nimukei Yosef** explains that "Kol Nidrei" is not an act of Hataras Nedarim for either past Nedarim or future ones. Rather, it is a prayer to Hashem that He not punish us for the past Nedarim that we made and transgressed.

Worth checking out the link for other *shitot* quoted.